# ios admod interstitial network adapter

Tags: ios, admob, iad

I'm working on a project that should show an interstitial banner between two UIViewController.

I'm using admob and my customer has provided me the interstitial unit id (that should be equals to mediation id).

I've downloaded the example project (https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/advanced?hl=it) and I have added my id into the project.
But I receive always this error:

> 2013-07-02 16:11:09.265 InterstitialExample[5289:c07]  Cannot
>   find an ad network adapter with the name(s): (
>       "com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter" ). Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC -all_load in
>   the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target.

I've also added the string -all_load into the "Other Linker Flags" section with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

The client provided you with an Interstitial ad unit ID targeted to Android. They'll need to create one for iOS specifically.

Side note: For linker flags, if you're using the latest SDK, you'll only need to include `-ObjC`.